# Modify db parameter group in AWS RDS using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

Trying to modify a database parameter group on AWS RDS with boto, I hit upon the error below:

```
from boto import rds
conn = rds.connect_to_region('eu-west-1', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,     aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
pg = conn.get_all_dbparameters('mygroup')
pg.add_param('slow_query_log', True, 'immediate')


TypeError
"unknown type (<type 'str'>)"
 File: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/boto/rds/parametergroup.py, Line: 175
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This seems to have been a bug in older versions of boto, that should be fixed now: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/844

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pg = conn.get_all_dbparameters('mygroup')
pg2 = conn.get_all_dbparameters('mygroup', marker = pg.Marker)
pg2['slow_query_log'].value = True
pg2['slow_query_log'].apply(True)
```

The conn.get_all_dbparameters() method returns max. 100 rows. However there are about 180 DB Parameters that can be modified. Therefore you have query in two steps. The first method call returns a Marker that you can use for your second query. In the second query you will have your slow_query_log available

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/rds.html#boto.rds.RDSConnection.get_all_dbparameter_groups

Comment: I get an unhandled key error because 'slow query log' apparently doesn't exist within the parameter group

Comment: Thanks... nearly there!. Just had to change the last line to pg2['slow_query_log'].apply(True)

Comment: It looks like the second line should be conn.get_all_dbparameters(...), rds does not have a method called get_all_dbparameters

Comment: Why not just use `connection.get_all_dbparameters('mygroup', max_records=200)`?

Comment: @DavePeck, because max_records is limited to 100. Unfortunately, you get this error if you try to retrieve any more records in one go:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-04-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Invalid value for max records. Must be between 20 and 100</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>ce1e6a57-3650-11e3-b92d-4f0d3452c8f6</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>